# Line/Mic in, how to use my MIC

Tags: audio, microphone, dell-optiplex

I am using **Dell Optiplex 960** machine and I want to use MIC on rear panel but here is a little issue. I know that *Line In* can't work with headset's mic and I have only one *Jack In* with both icons of *Line In* and *Mic In*.

After plugging in mic jack, windows shows that something is plugged in but doesn't catch my voice, don't know why.

Here is the rear picture of my machine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers for such a machine (I have several Latitude D series that work the same way), when they detect that you've plugged something in, are supposed to prompt you - "is this a mic or line input?" Selecting "mic" switches a preamp into the circuit and also enables the "ring" on the TRS plug to emit +5 VDC, which is used to power the mic itself.

It sounds like your system is defaulting to line input and not asking you.

There is an option in that dialog to "not ask again". If you ever selected it for line input and checked this option, well, there you are. There should be an option in the Control Panel - Sound - Recording settings to undo this.

Also: be sure the microphone input is set as the default recording device.

**Be sure you have the Dell drivers for your sound card.**  (The drivers that come with 10 will handle your chip in a "generic" way but they won't know about how the jacks are wired.) Assuming you're using Windows, go to the Dell support site for your machine and download the latest drivers. If they don't have one for your OS, just use the latest one that matches your OS's "bitness" and it will probably be fine - it always has been for me.

(Update - OP says they installed the Win7 driver in their system and it works fine and solved the problem.)

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and it didn't ask when I plugged-in my MIC in rear Jack-In.

Comment: Dell doesn't have drivers for Windows 10 on the Opti 960 and they say they won't be developing them. But they do have drivers for Windows 7,  and those should work ok on 10. (Some types of drivers aren't forward-compatible, but sound card drivers should be.) Just be sure to select the right OS (32-  vs 64-bit) before you download - notice the "Change OS" selector. http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/optiplex-960/drivers

Comment: You are right. I have installed windows 7 audio drivers in windows 10 and it works fine, I just plugged-in my MIC on rear panel and it asked either it Line-in device or MIC and I selected MIC.
I think you should update the answer.

Comment: Cool! If you'll just click the "accepted answer" or whatever the button is, that'll be sufficient. Thank you for the feedback!